# I want to generate Serial numbers starting from 1 in table

Tags: lightning-web-components

For me the serial Numbers are getting generated from 0
[image]

I want it to start from 1
this is the code that i have written

```
<template for:each={poplist} for:item="lst" for:index="index">
  <tr key={lst}>             
     <td>{index}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

This is the js code

```
handlePOSelection(event){
this.purchaseOrd = event.detail;
getproductsdetails({pursOrd: this.purchaseOrd})
.then(result => {

this.poplist=result;
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error>>'+error);
});
```

}

Comment: if i use {index + 1} i get an error: Invalid expression {index + 1} - LWC1060: Template expression doesn't allow BinaryExpression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWC does not support evaluated expression in markup.
You can try below approach to add an index property in your array of objects. Here , we use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) of ES6 to add index property.

In js :

```
handlePOSelection(event){
    this.purchaseOrd = event.detail;
    getproductsdetails({pursOrd: this.purchaseOrd})
    .then(result => {
    
    let resultArray=result;
    this.poplist = resultArray.map((record, index) => {
      return {...record,index: index+1};
    }); 
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error>>'+error);
```

});

In markup :

```
<template for:each={poplist} for:item="lst" for:index="index">
  <tr key={lst}>
    <td>{lst.index}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: i get a component error occured. this code doesn't work

Comment: If you can post the complete code , we can help you better. Above is an approach which you need to build on.

Comment: i posted the js code it basically gets the record details using apex class and we display it in the table

Comment: Updated the answer , please check.

Comment: Does it fix your issues ?

Comment: Yes its working. Thank You.

Comment: Can you check this question @Rohit https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396411/i-have-a-table-where-when-i-click-on-add-more-transactions-another-row-is-displa